# Как настроить корректное построение маршрута на карте(MKMapKit)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Строю маршрут между двумя точками, вместо маршрута по автодороге строится маршрут напрямую.

[image: map]

Что нужно настроить, чтобы маршрут строился по автодороге?

Comment: Уточните - вы сами строите маршрут? или какой-то библиотекой?

Comment: self.mapView наследник от MKMapView

Comment: вам надо чтоб путь проходил по точкам вами поставленным, или или чтобы карта вам дала directions?

Comment: нужно чтобы в конечном итоге при выборе аннотации путь прокладывался от userLocation до аннотации.

Comment: у вас на скриншоте это и есть - путь от userlocation до аннотации

Comment: да, я имею ввиду чтобы путь строился не напрямую через дома, а только по проезжей части.

Comment: не думаю, что по Минску получится это сделать :) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_MKDirections_to_get_iOS_7_Map_Directions_and_Routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем

```
 MKPolyline *lines;
```

Пример моей корявой функции. Где latitude,longitude - куда нам нужно проложить путь, curPosition.coordinate.latitude,curPosition.coordinate.longitude - откуда.

```
-(void)routeGo:(double)latitude long:(double)longitude
    {
        NSArray *pointsArray = [mapview overlays];

        [mapview removeOverlays:pointsArray];
        MKPlacemark *source = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(curPosition.coordinate.latitude,curPosition.coordinate.longitude) addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

        MKMapItem *srcMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:source];
        [srcMapItem setName:@""];

        MKPlacemark *destination = [[MKPlacemark alloc]initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude) addressDictionary:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"",@"", nil] ];

        MKMapItem *distMapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc]initWithPlacemark:destination];
        [distMapItem setName:@""];

        MKDirectionsRequest *request = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc]init];
        [request setSource:srcMapItem];
        [request setDestination:distMapItem];
        [request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny];

        MKDirections *direction = [[MKDirections alloc]initWithRequest:request];

        [direction calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"response = %@",response);
            NSArray *arrRoutes = [response routes];
            [arrRoutes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                MKRoute *rout = obj;

                MKPolyline *line = [rout polyline];
                lines = line;
                NSLog(@"Rout Name : %@",rout.name);
                NSLog(@"Total Distance (in Meters) :%f",rout.distance);

                NSArray *steps = [rout steps];

                NSLog(@"Total Steps : %d",[steps count]);

                [steps enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                    NSLog(@"Rout Instruction : %@",[obj instructions]);
                    NSLog(@"Rout Distance : %f",[obj distance]);
                }];
            }];
        }];
    }
```

У тебя есть выбор как проложить:

```
//[request setTransportType:MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny]
MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile //Будто ты на автомобиле
MKDirectionsTransportTypeWalking    //Пешком
MKDirectionsTransportTypeAny
```

Отображаем наш путь

```
[self.mapview addOverlay:lines];
```

Прошу прощение если криво - вырвано из моей программы. Если будут вопросы или ошибки обращайся :)